# Insert a character in string (indexof)

Tags: string, vb.net, character

what I want to do is insert a desired character like a "space" into a desired string like "123456789" at a specific point. Example: insert a space at the position 5 in the string 123456789 = 1234 56789. Here is my code:

```
    Dim str As String = sum2.Text '123456789
    Dim insStr As String = " " 'space
    Dim strRes As String = str.Insert(5, insStr) '5th position
```

the code looks fine and i dont get any errors when i use it or run it but it will not add the space at the 5th position so i need some help!

Comment: Works just fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FtzaVW   Are you sure `sum2` is filled? EDIT: Oh you want `1234 56789` Remember, arrays are 0 based. Use `4` instead of `5`.

Comment: Perhaps OP is expecting the space to appear in sum2.Text, which makes no sense given that he's working on a copy of the string.

Comment: its not adding the space at all anywhere, im confused, im using VS 2012 and framework 4.5 with all the imports i need

Comment: @alan7811 where are you checking for the inserted space? If you are looking at `str` for it you will not find it. `Insert` doesn't modify the string you ran it on, it creates a new string with the result of the operation. Check in `strResult` and you will see the space at position **6** because that method is zero based.

Answer (score 5):

You must not that the startIndex in `String.Insert(Integer, String)` is zero based. That means if your intention is to insert a space in the 5th position, you will have to adjust that by -1:

```
Dim insertPosition = 5 ' Assuming this came from the user who says put it in position 5
Dim inStr = " "
Dim strRes = str.Insert(insertPosition - 1, inStr) ' assuming your str already had a value.
```

That will insert the space between 4 and 5 and will produce

> 1234 56789

I saw in one your comments that you might want to insert spaces in positions 1,5,7. In that case, you will have to do it in reverse, starting with the largest position, to the smallest. This is of cause assuming that you wanted

> _1234_6_89

I have used underscores to represent spaces so that you can see it better.

Before working with that, ensure that your string has enough characters to be indexed by your index otherwise you'll get a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.